# Calculating modelview matrix for 2D camera using Eigen

Tags: math, opengl, matrix, camera, eigen

I'm trying to calculate modelview matrix of my 2D camera but I can't get the formula right. I use the Affine3f transform class so the matrix is compatible with OpenGL. This is closest that I did get by trial and error. This code rotates and scales the camera ok, but if I apply translation and rotation at same time the camera movement gets messed up: camera moves in rotated fashion, which is not what I want. (And this probaly due to fact I first apply the rotation matrix and then translation)

```
Eigen::Affine3f modelview;
modelview.setIdentity();
modelview.translate(Eigen::Vector3f(camera_offset_x, camera_offset_y, 0.0f));
modelview.scale(Eigen::Vector3f(camera_zoom_x, camera_zoom_y, 0.0f));
modelview.rotate(Eigen::AngleAxisf(camera_angle, Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ()));
modelview.translate(Eigen::Vector3f(camera_x, camera_y, 0.0f));
[loadmatrix_to_gl]
```

What I want is that camera would rotate and scale around offset position in screenspace {(0,0) is middle of the screen in this case} and then be positioned along the global xy-axes in worldspace {(0,0) is also initialy at middle of the screen} to the final position. How would I do this?

Note that I have set up also an orthographic projection matrix, which may affect this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 2D image, rendered in the XY plane with OpenGL, to *(1)* rotate counter-clockwise by **a** around point **P**, *(2)* scale by **S**, and then *(3)* translate so that pixels at **C** (in the newly scaled and rotated image) are at the origin, you would use this transformation:

1. translate by **-P** (this moves the pixels at **P** to the origin)
2. rotate by **a**
3. translate by **P** (this moves the origin back to where it was)
4. scale by **S**  (if you did this earlier, your rotation would be messed up)
5. translate by **-C**

If the 2D image we being rendered at the origin, you'd also need to end by translate by some value along the negative z axis to be able to see it.

Normally, you'd just do this with OpenGL basics (`glTranslatef`, `glScalef`, `glRotatef`, etc.).  And you would do them in the reverse order that I've listed them.  Since you want to use `glLoadMatrix`, you'd do things in the order I described with Eigen.  It's important to remember that OpenGL is expecting a Column Major matrix (but that seems to be the default for Eigen; so that's probably not a problem).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work better now. However the camera isn't moving in way I excpected: increasing x-coordinate will also affect y-coordinate so the camera moves along the rotated xy-axes instead of unrotated xy-axes. This was the second part of my problem to get the camera moving as I wanted. I want the camera to just rotate and scale around point and then move the camera to its position in the way that the applied rotation does not affect this translation.
PS: I'm going to avoid fixed-pipeline stuff much as possible so change to GL 3.0 + shaders and newer would be painless.

Comment: @JATothrim I glanced at the Eigen spec.  It says that the transformations you're using are applied to the right of the matrix.  I was expecting them to be applied at the left.  Since they're applied at the right, you need to apply them in the reverse order.  Alternatively, you can use "prerotate" and "pretranslate".

Comment: It's so close but not quite. The camera now rotates and zooms around point and it translates okay if there is no rotation. The rotation messes up the translation (or vice versa) and the camera won't _move_ like I'm excepting it to do. Rotate 90 degree and y axis turns into x axis in the camera movement! How do I prevent this?

Comment: I think I have solved this moving problem finaly. The Error was that I reseted the modelview to identity every frame, even when moving the camera relatively to its current placement. Because of this extracting the X vector from the modelview and then translating in that direction didn't work! I feel so stupid now. C:
Lesson: it's okay to chain transformations endlessly without ever going back to identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

JCooper did great explaining the steps to construct the initial matrix.

However I eventually solved the problem bit differently. There was few additional things and steps that were not obvious for me at the time. See JCooper answer's comments. First is to realize all matrix operations are *relative*.

Thus if you want to position or move the camera with *absolute xy-axes*, you must first decompose the matrix to extract its absolute position with unchanged axes. Then you translate the matrix by the difference of the old and new position.

Here is way to do this with Eigen:

First compute Affine2f matrix `cmat` scalar determinant D. With Eigen this is done with `D = cmat.linear().determinant();`. Next compute 'reverse' matrix `matrev` of the current rotation+scale matrix R using the D. `matrev = (RS.array() / (1.0f / determ)).matrix());` where RS is `cmat.matrix().topLeftCorner(2,2)`
The absolute camera position P is then given by `P = invmat * -C` where C is `cmat.matrix().col(2).head<2>()`

Now we can reposition the camera anywhere along the absolute axes and keeping the rotation+scaling same: V = RS * (T - P) where RS is same as before, T is the new position vec and P is the decomposed position vec.
The `cmat` then simply translated by V to move the camera: `cmat.pretranslate(V)`